# Comparing the Speed of Random Number Generation to Reading Data

Tags: complexity-theory, random-number-generator, storage

Imagine you need $n$ random numbers from a Gaussian distribution with $\mu=0$ and $\sigma=1$. And you need to use each of these $n$ numbers $k$ times in various operations. Let's identify the numbers by $j \in 1 \ldots n$.

I see 3 methods of accessing these $n$ numbers during the operations:

1. Generate $n$ numbers once, store them in memory and read each one $k$ times.
2. Generate $n$ numbers once, store them on disk and read each one $k$ times.
3. Set the generator's seed to $j$ and generate the number $n * k$ times.

To determine the total run time, let's define the following terms:

- $T_{rand}$: the time to generate 1 random number
- $T_{seed}$: the time to set the seed
- $T_{w,mem}$: the time to store 1 number in memory
- $T_{w,dis}$: the time to store 1 number on disk
- $T_{s,mem}$: the time to search 1 number in memory
- $T_{s,dis}$: the time to search 1 number on disk
- $T_{r,mem}$: the time to read 1 number from memory
- $T_{r,dis}$: the time to read 1 number from disk

I believe the total run time for the three methods are:

1. $T_{total,1} = n * T_{rand}+ n * T_{w,mem} + n * k * T_{s,mem} + n * k * T_{r,mem}$
2. $T_{total,2} = n * T_{rand}+ n * T_{w,dis} + n * k * T_{s,dis} + n * k * T_{r,dis}$
3. $T_{total,3} = n * T_{seed}+ n * k * T_{rand}$

It would seem strangely coincidental to me if these three methods had similar speeds. I can imagine one of them vastly outperforms the others. This is were I would like some advice. If helpful, you may assume:

- Number $n$ is large; possible so large that storing $n$ values in memory is not possible.
- The randomness can be of low quality.
- Storing and reading from disk is done efficiently, e.g. with Hadoop.

My questions are:

- Do you see other methods to solve this problem?
- What other information do I need to determine which method is the fastest?
- Which aspects of the procedure will dominate in determining the total time it takes?
- Which method is the fastest? And, if possible, why?

Comment: This question is incomplete in that:  there are two types of random number generator.  One is the plain  type like random().  The second is a cryptographic ally secure one where future output cannot be predicted from past output. The latter is much harder so affects the question.  Which do you want?

Comment: Further, what's the point of a naff RNG?  How naff also affects the question, so what are you trying to achieve? Can you simply alternate between 0.003 and -1.7777, because that's pretty naff too?

Comment: Why not empirically test the various methods?

Comment: @PaulUszak Let's assume the RNG need not be cryptographically secure. What is 'naff'?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Good point, though I would not be surprised if one of these methods is obviously better than the others, in a wide range of situations. I am simply not familiar enough with CS to judge this myself.

Comment: A reference to Hadoop as a guarantee of disk access efficiency is rather... surrealistic.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Is it?! Can you explain? As mentioned, I'm not experienced, but I thought the whole point of HDFS was quick access... Anyone else care to weigh in?

Comment: The point is quick *concurrent* accesses. But nothing stresses a hard disk more than concurrent accesses. You don't need them here, don't create a bottleneck.

Comment: Who downvoted this question? And why?!

Comment: @YuvalFilmus You seem to have gotten some up-votes for your comment, but that bothers me. There are obvious reasons why an empirical test is **not** a good idea. First, a junior or medior developer would spend a lot of time setting up such a test. Perhaps this is not worth the effort. Secondly, for such non-experts, whatever result some out of the test is not trustworthy: any discrepancy in time could simply be due to them setting up one of the tests in a sub-optimal fashion. Empirical tests are only useful when you're an expert and you can trust your own work.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is completely computer-architecture and random-generator -dependent. All you can do is to benchmark the different approaches after making them concrete.

Comment: A few years ago, IBM had published a linear congruential random number generator for their high end POWER cpus that ran at one cycle per number throughput. It requires an FPU with fused multiply-add, so it should be possible to adapt it to modern Intel processors.

Comment: @gnasher729: Intel processors even have a built-in nondeterministic RNG nowadays.